# Удаление дубликатов по двум полям. Игнорируется ORDER BY в операторе DELETE

Tags: mysql, mariadb

v. 10.11.5-MariaDB.

Имеется таблица t1:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
    `str` TEXT DEFAULT '',
    `cnt` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Для примера заполнена следующими данными:

```
+-----+-----+
| str | cnt |
+-----+-----+
| aaa |   1 |
| aaa |   2 |
| aaa |   3 |
| aaa |   7 |
| aaa |   4 |
| bbb |   1 |
| bbb |   2 |
| bbb |   8 |
| bbb |   3 |
+-----+-----+
```

Задача удалить дубликаты по полю `str`, оставив только записи соответствующие максимальным значениям в поле `cnt`. Для приведенного примера это - ('ааа',7) и ('bbb',8).

Делаю проверку SELECT-ом:

```
SET @lastStr = '';
SELECT @lastStr, IF(str = @lastStr, 1, (@lastStr:=str) AND 0) AS toDelete, t1.* FROM t1 
ORDER BY str ASC, cnt DESC;
+----------+----------+-----+-----+
| @lastStr | toDelete | str | cnt |
+----------+----------+-----+-----+
|          |        0 | aaa |   7 |
| aaa      |        1 | aaa |   4 |
| aaa      |        1 | aaa |   3 |
| aaa      |        1 | aaa |   2 |
| aaa      |        1 | aaa |   1 |
| aaa      |        0 | bbb |   8 |
| bbb      |        1 | bbb |   3 |
| bbb      |        1 | bbb |   2 |
| bbb      |        1 | bbb |   1 |
+----------+----------+-----+-----+
```

Видно что должны остаться 2 записи с максимальными значениями `cnt` (поле toDelete в выборке равно нулю). Пробуем удалить дубликаты тем же подходом:

```
SET @lastStr = '';
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE  IF(str = @lastStr, 1, (@lastStr:=str) AND 0)
ORDER BY str ASC, cnt DESC;
SELECT * FROM t1;
+-----+-----+
| str | cnt |
+-----+-----+
| aaa |   1 |
| bbb |   1 |
+-----+-----+
```

Остаются только первые записи. ORDER BY в операторе DELETE игнорируется? почему?

Аналогичная ситуация с UPDATE, если дубликатам в поле str присвоить значение NULL:

```
SET @lastStr = '';
UPDATE t1 SET str=null WHERE IF(str = @lastStr, 1, (@lastStr:=str) AND 0)
ORDER BY str ASC, cnt DESC;
SELECT * FROM t1;
+------+-----+
| str  | cnt |
+------+-----+
| aaa  |   1 |
| NULL |   2 |
| NULL |   3 |
| NULL |   7 |
| NULL |   4 |
| bbb  |   1 |
| NULL |   2 |
| NULL |   8 |
| NULL |   3 |
+------+-----+
```

Comment: А разве в `DELETE` вообще `ORDER BY` допустим? Я что-то первый раз такое вижу. Хотя всё может быть.

Comment: В документации на mysql написано что ``ORDER BY`` допустим в ``DELETE`` и что он рабоатет в сочетании с ``LIMIT``

Comment: Добавил "LIMIT 10" в оператор DELETE. Результат тот же...

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE t11.*
FROM t1 AS t11
JOIN t1 AS t12 USING (str)
WHERE t11.cnt < t12.cnt;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/41Zy6Z_6

Но если две или более записей для одного `str` имеют одинаковый и при этом максимальный `cnt` - останутся обе записи.

Comment: К сожалению, дубликаты с равными максимальными cnt нужно удалять. Похоже все-таки придется создавать отдельную таблицу t2 с Primary id-шниками тех записей из t1, которые нужно удалить.  Заполнить ее приведенным в топике SELECT-ом. А затем циклом в процедуре удалять из основной таблицы порциями, так как записей много. Ну и шлифануть для фен-шуя OPTIMIZE TABLE t1.

Comment: @user305545 А в таблица на самом деле всего два поля и нет первичного ключа?

Comment: в рабочей таблице  с десяток полей и первичный ключ INT, +дополнительные индексы по текстовым полям и комбинированные  (text + INT) для тестов. В топике упростил до двух полей для описания проблемы ORDER BY в операторах DELETE и UPDATE.

Comment: @user305545 Ну так если есть первичный ключ, то всё прекрасно. `.. WHERE t11.cnt < t12.cnt OR (t11.cnt = t12.cnt AND t11.id < t12.id);`

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
    `str` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `cnt` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

 INSERT INTO t1 (str,  cnt ) VALUES  ('aaa' ,  1 ),
 ('aaa' ,  2 ),
 ('aaa' ,  3 ),
 ('aaa' ,  7 ),
 ('aaa' ,  4 ),
 ('bbb' ,  1 ),
 ('bbb' ,  2 ),
 ('bbb' ,  8 ),
 ('bbb' ,  3 );

DELETE t1 FROM t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `str`, MAX(`cnt`) as max_cnt
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY `str`
) t2 ON t1.`str` = t2.`str`
WHERE t1.`cnt` < t2.max_cnt;

select * from t1;
```

---

```
Output:

+-----+-----+
| str | cnt |
+-----+-----+
| aaa |   7 |
| bbb |   8 |
+-----+-----+
```

---

Explain

```
+------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | t1         | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9    |                                 |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9    | Using where                     |
|    2 | DERIVED     | t1         | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9    | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Я плохо читаю Explain, как я понял тут написано один раз проходим по всем данным 9 строк, второй раз проходим по всем данным Using where, помещаем во временную таблицу,  третий раз проходим по всем данным извлекая из временной таблицы. На других данных нужно проверять .

Comment: Спасибо. Это понятно. Но как этот способ будет работать на ооооочень больших данных (2-3млрд записей)? Даже в случае индекса по полю str. СУБД создаст временную таблицу для подзапроса или будет пытаться все это проделать в оперативной памяти?

Comment: @user305545 нужно проверять на актуальных данных.